# Reading excel file in c# using Microsoft DocumentFormat.OpenXml SDK

Tags: c#, excel

I am using Microsoft DocumentFormat.OpenXml SDK to read data from excel file.
While doing so I am taking into consideration if a cell has blank values(If Yes, read that too).

Now, facing issues with one of the excel sheets where the workSheet.SheetDimension is null hence the code is throwing an exception.

Code used :

class OpenXMLHelper
    {
        //  A helper function to open an Excel file using OpenXML, and return a DataTable containing all the data from one
        //  of the worksheets.
        //
        //  We've had lots of problems reading in Excel data using OLEDB (eg the ACE drivers no longer being present on new servers,
        //  OLEDB not working due to security issues, and blatantly ignoring blank rows at the top of worksheets), so this is a more 
        //  stable method of reading in the data.
        //

```
    public static DataTable ExcelWorksheetToDataTable(string pathFilename)
    {
        try
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string dimensions = string.Empty;

            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(pathFilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            {
                using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fs, false))
                {
                    // Find the sheet with the supplied name, and then use that 
                    // Sheet object to retrieve a reference to the first worksheet.
                    //Sheet theSheet = document.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().Where(s => s.Name == worksheetName).FirstOrDefault();
                    //--Sheet theSheet = document.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().FirstOrDefault();

                    //--if (theSheet == null)
                    //--    throw new Exception("Couldn't find the worksheet: "+ theSheet.Id);

                    // Retrieve a reference to the worksheet part.
                    //WorksheetPart wsPart = (WorksheetPart)(document.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(theSheet.Id));
                    //--WorksheetPart wsPart = (WorksheetPart)(document.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(theSheet.Id));

                    WorkbookPart workbookPart = document.WorkbookPart;
                    WorksheetPart wsPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.FirstOrDefault();
                    Worksheet workSheet = wsPart.Worksheet;

                    dimensions = workSheet.SheetDimension.Reference.InnerText;       //  Get the dimensions of this worksheet, eg "B2:F4"

                    int numOfColumns = 0;
                    int numOfRows = 0;
                    CalculateDataTableSize(dimensions, ref numOfColumns, ref numOfRows);
                    //System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("The worksheet \"{0}\" has dimensions \"{1}\", so we need a DataTable of size {2}x{3}.", worksheetName, dimensions, numOfColumns, numOfRows));

                    SheetData sheetData = workSheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
                    IEnumerable<Row> rows = sheetData.Descendants<Row>();

                    string[,] cellValues = new string[numOfColumns, numOfRows];

                    int colInx = 0;
                    int rowInx = 0;
                    string value = "";
                    SharedStringTablePart stringTablePart = document.WorkbookPart.SharedStringTablePart;

                    //  Iterate through each row of OpenXML data, and store each cell's value in the appropriate slot in our [,] string array.
                    foreach (Row row in rows)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < row.Descendants<Cell>().Count(); i++)
                        {
                            //  *DON'T* assume there's going to be one XML element for each column in each row...
                            Cell cell = row.Descendants<Cell>().ElementAt(i);
                            if (cell.CellValue == null || cell.CellReference == null)
                                continue;                       //  eg when an Excel cell contains a blank string

                            //  Convert this Excel cell's CellAddress into a 0-based offset into our array (eg "G13" -> [6, 12])
                            colInx = GetColumnIndexByName(cell.CellReference);             //  eg "C" -> 2  (0-based)
                            rowInx = GetRowIndexFromCellAddress(cell.CellReference) - 1;     //  Needs to be 0-based

                            //  Fetch the value in this cell
                            value = cell.CellValue.InnerXml;
                            if (cell.DataType != null && cell.DataType.Value == CellValues.SharedString)
                            {
                                value = stringTablePart.SharedStringTable.ChildElements[Int32.Parse(value)].InnerText;
                            }

                            cellValues[colInx, rowInx] = value;
                        }
                    }

                    //  Copy the array of strings into a DataTable.
                    //  We don't (currently) make any attempt to work out which columns should be numeric, rather than string.
                    for (int col = 0; col < numOfColumns; col++)
                    {
                        //dt.Columns.Add("Column_" + col.ToString());
                        dt.Columns.Add(cellValues[col, 0]);
                    }

                    //foreach (Cell cell in rows.ElementAt(0))
                    //{
                    //    dt.Columns.Add(GetCellValue(doc, cell));
                    //}


                    for (int row = 0; row < numOfRows; row++)
                    {
                        DataRow dataRow = dt.NewRow();
                        for (int col = 0; col < numOfColumns; col++)
                        {
                            dataRow.SetField(col, cellValues[col, row]);
                        }
                        dt.Rows.Add(dataRow);
                    }

                    dt.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
                    //#if DEBUG
                    //                //  Write out the contents of our DataTable to the Output window (for debugging)
                    //                string str = "";
                    //                for (rowInx = 0; rowInx < maxNumOfRows; rowInx++)
                    //                {
                    //                    for (colInx = 0; colInx < maxNumOfColumns; colInx++)
                    //                    {
                    //                        object val = dt.Rows[rowInx].ItemArray[colInx];
                    //                        str += (val == null) ? "" : val.ToString();
                    //                        str += "\t";
                    //                    }
                    //                    str += "\n";
                    //                }
                    //                System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(str);
                    //#endif
                    return dt;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }

    }

    public static void CalculateDataTableSize(string dimensions, ref int numOfColumns, ref int numOfRows)
    {
        //  How many columns & rows of data does this Worksheet contain ?  
        //  We'll read in the Dimensions string from the Excel file, and calculate the size based on that.
        //      eg "B1:F4" -> we'll need 6 columns and 4 rows.
        //
        //  (We deliberately ignore the top-left cell address, and just use the bottom-right cell address.)
        try
        {
            string[] parts = dimensions.Split(':');     // eg "B1:F4" 
            if (parts.Length != 2)
                throw new Exception("Couldn't find exactly *two* CellAddresses in the dimension");

            numOfColumns = 1 + GetColumnIndexByName(parts[1]);     //  A=1, B=2, C=3  (1-based value), so F4 would return 6 columns
            numOfRows = GetRowIndexFromCellAddress(parts[1]);
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new Exception("Could not calculate maximum DataTable size from the worksheet dimension: " + dimensions);
        }
    }

    public static int GetRowIndexFromCellAddress(string cellAddress)
    {
        //  Convert an Excel CellReference column into a 1-based row index
        //  eg "D42"  ->  42
        //     "F123" ->  123
        string rowNumber = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(cellAddress, "[^0-9 _]", "");
        return int.Parse(rowNumber);
    }

    public static int GetColumnIndexByName(string cellAddress)
    {
        //  Convert an Excel CellReference column into a 0-based column index
        //  eg "D42" ->  3
        //     "F123" -> 5
        var columnName = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(cellAddress, "[^A-Z_]", "");
        int number = 0, pow = 1;
        for (int i = columnName.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            number += (columnName[i] - 'A' + 1) * pow;
            pow *= 26;
        }
        return number - 1;
    }
}[enter image description here][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `SheetDimension` part is optional (and therefor you cannot always rely on it being up to date). See the following part of the OpenXML specification:

> 18.3.1.35 dimension (Worksheet Dimensions)
>
> This element specifies the used range of the worksheet. It specifies the row and column bounds of
>   used cells in the worksheet. **This is optional and is not required**.
>   Used cells include cells with formulas, text content, and cell
>   formatting. When an entire column is formatted, only the first cell in
>   that column is considered used.

So an Excel file without any `SheetDimension` part is perfectly valid, so you should not rely on it being present in an Excel file.

Therefor I'd suggest to simply parse all `Row` elements contained in the `SheetData` part, and "count" the number of rows (instead of reading the `SheetDimensions` part to get the number of rows / columns). This way you can also take into account that an Excel file may contain completely blank rows in-between the data.

Comment: Just parsing rows is not fetching the required result.
Issue : 
Row 1 : 5 Cells (All having values)
Row 2 : 6 Cells (Cell 1,2 are blank).

So what is happening is while putting data is Row 1 will be printed as it is but row 2 has 2 blank cells which get shifted to the left while inserting to the datatable. Because of this I was taking the SheetDimension into consideration.
Any suggestions how this can be solved.
A code snippet would give more clarity.